# Breadth-First-Search results vs Depth-First-Search results confusing

Tags: python, numpy, artificial-intelligence

I implemented a problem solving agent program, to solve the classic 8-puzzle problem, using a Node and Problem class as described in Peter Norvig's "AI a Modern Approach 3rd Ed."

I then solve the puzzle with both a Breadth-First-Search (BFS) and then a Depth-First-Search (DFS) of the state space. Although both find a solution, I am confused about the solution arrived at by the DFS. The BFS solves the puzzle with 12 moves, but the DFS solves it with over a 100 moves and that does not seem right.

Part of my implementation traces the route from the goal or final node back to the root node. I would expect both algorithms to produce the same result (i.e. 12 moves) as they both use the same class method to trace the route; and I assume that both algorithms would identify the same node as the goal node. So unless my assumption here is wrong, I either have an error in my code or there are multiple solutions to the puzzle.

```
import numpy as np
initial_board = np.array([[1,2,3],
                      [4,0,5],
                      [6,7,8]])
initial_space = (1,1)
initial_state=[initial_action,(initial_board,initial_space)]

goal_board = np.array([[1,2,3],
                   [4,5,6],
                   [0,7,8]])
goal_space = (2,0)
goal_state = [goal_board,goal_space]


class Problem:
"""The abstract class for a formal problem. You should subclass
this and implement the methods actions and result, and possibly
__init__, goal_test, and path_cost. Then you will create instances
of your subclass and solve them with the various search functions."""

def __init__(self, initial, goal=None):
    """The constructor specifies the initial state, and possibly a goal
    state, if there is a unique goal. Your subclass's constructor can add
    other arguments."""
    self.initial = initial
    self.goal = goal

def actions(self, state):
    """Return the actions that can be executed in the given
    state. The result would typically be a list, but if there are
    many actions, consider yielding them one at a time in an
    iterator, rather than building them all at once."""
    raise NotImplementedError

def result(self, state, action):
    """Return the state that results from executing the given
    action in the given state. The action must be one of
    self.actions(state)."""
    raise NotImplementedError

def goal_test(self, state):
    """Return True if the state is a goal. The default method compares the
    state to self.goal or checks for state in self.goal if it is a
    list, as specified in the constructor. Override this method if
    checking against a single self.goal is not enough."""
    if isinstance(self.goal, list):
        return is_in(state, self.goal)
    else:
        return state == self.goal

def path_cost(self, c, state1, action, state2):
    """Return the cost of a solution path that arrives at state2 from
    state1 via action, assuming cost c to get up to state1. If the problem
    is such that the path doesn't matter, this function will only look at
    state2. If the path does matter, it will consider c and maybe state1
    and action. The default method costs 1 for every step in the path."""
    return c + 1

def value(self, state):
    """For optimization problems, each state has a value. Hill Climbing
    and related algorithms try to maximize this value."""
    raise NotImplementedError

class PuzzleProblem(Problem):
def actions(self, state):
    """Return the actions that can be executed in the given
    state. The result would typically be a list, but if there are
    many actions, consider yielding them one at a time in an
    iterator, rather than building them all at once."""
    actions = []

    (row,col)  = state[1][1]
    
    if row > 0 :
        actions.append('U')
    if row < 2:
        actions.append('D')
    if col > 0:
        actions.append('L')
    if col < 2:
        actions.append('R')
    return actions

def result(self, state, action):
    """Return the state that results from executing the given
    action in the given state. The action must be one of
    self.actions(state)."""
    
    mat = state[1][0] 
    (row, col) = state[1][1]
    
    if action == 'U':
        mat1 = np.copy(mat)
        mat1[row][col] = mat1[row-1][col]
        mat1[row-1][col] = 0
        return [action,(mat1,(row-1,col))]
    if action == 'D':
        mat1 = np.copy(mat)
        mat1[row][col] = mat1[row+1][col]
        mat1[row+1][col] = 0
        return [action,(mat1,(row+1,col))]
    if action == 'L':
        mat1 = np.copy(mat)
        mat1[row][col] = mat1[row][col-1]
        mat1[row][col-1] = 0
        return [action,(mat1,(row,col-1))]
    if action == 'R':
        mat1 = np.copy(mat)
        mat1[row][col] = mat1[row][col+1]
        mat1[row][col+1] = 0
        return [action,(mat1,(row,col+1))]

def goal_test(self, state):
    """Return True if the state is a goal. The default method compares the
    state to self.goal or checks for state in self.goal if it is a
    list, as specified in the constructor. Override this method if
    checking against a single self.goal is not enough."""
    #print('State to test: ')
    #print(state[1][0])
    #file1.write(str(state[1][0]))
    if isinstance(self.goal, list):
        if (np.all(state[1][0] == self.goal[0])) and (state[1][1] == self.goal[1]):
            print('GOAL REACHED')
            return True
        else:
            return False

puzzle = PuzzleProblem(initial_state,goal_state)

from collections import deque

class Node:
"""A node in a search tree. Contains a pointer to the parent (the node
that this is a successor of) and to the actual state for this node. Note
that if a state is arrived at by two paths, then there are two nodes with
the same state. Also includes the action that got us to this state, and
the total path_cost (also known as g) to reach the node. Other functions
may add an f and h value; see best_first_graph_search and astar_search for
an explanation of how the f and h values are handled. You will not need to
subclass this class."""

def __init__(self, state, parent=None, action=None, path_cost=0):
    """Create a search tree Node, derived from a parent by an action."""
    self.state = state
    self.parent = parent
    self.action = action
    self.path_cost = path_cost
    self.depth = 0
    if parent:
        self.depth = parent.depth + 1

def __repr__(self):
    return "<Node {}>".format(self.state)

def __lt__(self, node):
    return self.state < node.state

def expand(self, problem):
    """List the nodes reachable in one step from this node."""
    #return [self.child_node(problem, action) for action in problem.actions(self.state)]
    actions = problem.actions(self.state)
    action_results = []
    children = []
    
    for action in actions:
        action_results.append(problem.result(self.state,action))
        
    for action_state in action_results:
        children.append(self.child_node(problem,action_state[0]))
    return children    

def child_node(self, problem, action):
    """[Figure 3.10]"""
    next_state = problem.result(self.state, action)
    next_node = Node(next_state, self, action, problem.path_cost(self.path_cost, self.state, action, next_state))
    return next_node

def solution(self):
    """Return the sequence of actions to go from the root to this node."""
    #file2 = open("BFSNodes.txt","a")
    file4 = open("DFSNodes.txt","a")
    sol = [node.state[1][0] for node in self.path()[1:]]
    file4.writelines(str(sol))
    file4.close()
    return [node.action for node in self.path()[1:]]

def path(self):
    """Return a list of nodes forming the path from the root to this node."""
    node, path_back = self, []
    while node:
        path_back.append(node)
        node = node.parent
    return list(reversed(path_back))

# We want for a queue of nodes in breadth_first_graph_search or
# astar_search to have no duplicated states, so we treat nodes
# with the same state as equal. [Problem: this may not be what you
# want in other contexts.]

def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(other, Node) and self.state == other.state

def __hash__(self):
    # We use the hash value of the state
    # stored in the node instead of the node
    # object itself to quickly search a node
    # with the same state in a Hash Table
    return hash(self.state)

def not_in_explored(node,explored_list):
for n in explored_list:
    if (n.state[1][0] == node.state[1][0]).all():
        return False
return True

def breadth_first_tree_search(problem):
"""
[Figure 3.7]
Search the shallowest nodes in the search tree first.
Search through the successors of a problem to find a goal.
The argument frontier should be an empty queue.
Repeats infinitely in case of loops.
"""
frontier = deque([Node(problem.initial)])  # FIFO queue
explored_nodes = []
breaker = 0
file1 = open("BFSsol.txt","a")
while frontier:
    breaker +=1
    #print('BREAKER: ',breaker)
    if breaker > 1000000:
        print('breaking')
        break
    node = frontier.popleft()
    if not_in_explored(node,explored_nodes):
        explored_nodes.append(node)

        if problem.goal_test(node.state):
            solution = node.solution()
            file1.write(str(solution))
            file1.close()
            return solution
        frontier.extend(node.expand(problem))
return None

def depth_first_tree_search(problem):
"""
[Figure 3.7]
Search the deepest nodes in the search tree first.
Search through the successors of a problem to find a goal.
The argument frontier should be an empty queue.
Repeats infinitely in case of loops.
"""
file3 = open("DFSsol.txt","a")
explored_nodes = []
frontier = [Node(problem.initial)]  # Stack
breaker = 0

while frontier:
    breaker +=1
    #print(breaker)
    if breaker > 1000000:
        print('breaking')
        break
    node = frontier.pop()
    if not_in_explored(node,explored_nodes):
        explored_nodes.append(node)
        if problem.goal_test(node.state):
            solution = node.solution()
            file3.write(str(solution))
            file3.close()
            return solution
        frontier.extend(node.expand(problem))
return None

breadth_first_tree_search(puzzle)
depth_first_tree_search(puzzle)
```

The BFS derives this solution:
['R', 'D', 'L', 'L', 'U', 'R', 'D', 'R', 'U', 'L', 'L', 'D']

But the DFS derives many, many more moves.

I would expect both algorithms to derive at the 12-move solution and therefor do not understand why the DFS produces so many moves for a solution.

Can anyone point me to an error in the code; or explain the outcomes if it is correct?

Comment: Using a `numpy` array instead of a list of lists probably isn't helping you.  At least not with speed; it may not be hurting, though they have somewhat different behaviors on iteration and changing values.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is expected: DFS is *not* optimal, it will find solutions that are not necessarily the shortest. It just, as the name says, runs down the search tree in a depth-first manner, meaning it will never backtrack unless it has to. It returns the first solution it finds, using the first guess at every junction in the tree, and if there is none, tries the second, third, etc. So what it finds is not necessarily the shortest.

The upside of DFS is that it is more memory efficient. It doesn't need to keep track of several unfinished candidate plans because it always only considers one option.

Upshot: your code is quite possibly correct.